# Jquery Cycle 2 - Como fazer um resumo da Paginação?

Tags: jquery, cycle2

Como resumir a paginação do cycle2 para os demais itens da paginação irem aparecendo de acordo com as necessidades do usuário e também ele se encaixe num determinado container?

[image: Imagem exemplo]